# Class containing container with template objects

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

I have a class

```
class A{
vector<B> arr;
};
```

where

```
template <class T>
class B{
T member;
};
```

How want to be able to do something like

```
A container;
B<int> b1;
B<char> b2;
...
container.arr.push_back(b1);
container.arr.push_back(b2);
```

I tried adding template before class A, but i do not want to have to specify the template by class A, because then I wont be able to push objects of different types. How am I supposed to deal with this?

Comment: `vector<B>` is incorrect, because `B` is not a type, but a template

Comment: "...because then I wont be able to push objects of different types." is this your actual question? "How can i store objects of different types in a vector?"

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for something like [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).

Comment: this is a [xyproblem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). Please try to rephrase the question to include your actual problem not only your attempt to solve it (because your current attempt has some serious flaws and it isnt obvious how to fix them without knowing what you actually want to achieve)

Comment: No, this is not my question. Class B is template class and has array of single type objects, but i want class A to be able to store several class B objects and some of them may be with different instances of the template.

Comment: ..so you want to have objects of different types in the vector?

Comment: I have a class A, which has vector of objects of template class B. My question is how to specify the template for class A. This is neither xy problem nor polymorphism problem, @user463035818

Comment: to be clear: "I have a class A" , no you dont, because this code is not valid. You cannot have a vector of templates

Comment: to be clear2: in your example `b1` and `b2` are of different types that have nothing in common, so you cannot push them into the same vector

Comment: _"...  A to be able to store several class B objects ..."_ **NO**. There is no `class B`. There is a _template_ `B`. You can't store instances of a template. You can store instances of `B<int>` or of `B<char>` but not of `B` because by definition you don't know what that is yet.

Comment: template <typename T>  
class A{  
vector<B<T> > arr;  
};  
and it will NOT be possible to store different B with different T inside the same A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `template` is a compile-time code generation construct. In your code examples,  `B` is not a *type*, but a *template*.

Templates can be *instantiated* at compile-time to generate a type (e.g. `B<int>`).

---

`std::vector<T>` is a container template class parametrized on `T` - it can only store objects of type `T`.

If you want to store objects of different types in the same container, you can:

- Use `std::tuple<Ts...>` if you know the object sequence at compile-time;
- Use something like `std::vector<std::variant<A, B>>` if you don't know whether an object is `A` or `B` until run-time.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in some comments, storing variables of distinct types into a `std::vector` might not be a good idea, and in fact, if you need to do so, chances are these types have something in common such that you can find more suitable approaches for achieving your goals, such as creating a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base_Type>>`.

However, what you tried to do is still possible in a slightly different way using `std::any`.

```
template <typename T>
struct B
{
    T member;
};
// ...
std::vector<std::any> v;
B<int>  bi {123};
B<char> bc {'@'};
B<std::string> bs {"I am a string"};

v.push_back(bi);
v.push_back(bc);
v.push_back(bs);

// Go through vector. You will have to check for the type and
// cast it appropriately before doing anything useful.
for (auto x : v) {
    if (x.type() == typeid(B<int>))
        std::cout << std::any_cast<B<int>>(x).member << std::endl;
    else if (/* ... */)
        // ...
}
// ...
```

Another option could be a `std::vector` of `std::variant`s, as explained by Vittorio.