# Store any template of class in another class

Tags: c++, templates

If you want to store any templated class in another class, is there a way of doing that without extending from a non-templated base class. Example

class definition:

```cpp
class BaseA
{
    ...
}

class Storage
{
public:
    baseA* toStore;//pointer to baseA
}

template <typename... Type>
class ExtendedA : public baseA
{
    ...
}
```

using class:

```cpp
Storage a;
one.toStore = ExtendedA<int, char, etc...>();
```

This is the only way that I can think of storing a templated type in a non-templated class. Are there other ways to do this?

Comment: note that `ExtendedA<int, char, etc...>` is not a template nor a templated type as you call it but it is just a type. In general you cannot do anything with an instance of a template unless you instantiate the template and then its is a type as any other type

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642933/class-contaning-container-with-template-objects

Comment: @user463035818 - Yes, I am aware that it is only a type after intantiation. I was just curious if there was some c++ syntax for allowing a pointer to a "generic" templated type

Comment: @Donut Considering that different template specializations can differ wildly in interface due to features such as explicit specializations. There would be no way to use such a generic template pointer type for anything useful since it would not be known what interface the pointed object offers. In practice, such a pointer would be no more useful than a `void*`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - Alright. I was thinking that may be the case, but I wanted to make sure there wasn't something that I wasn't aware of. If you want to create an answer with that, I will approve it.

Comment: @Donut While there is no built-in pointer type to do what you're trying to do, there are workarounds using standard library types. See the proposed duplicate linked by NathanOliver.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to store and use a templated type, where the template is unknown, is to set up the classes in the same way as the example from the question.

Have a non-templated base class. 
Extend that base class, and template the extension. 
A pointer to the base class can now be stored, and used, even if it happens to be the templated extended class.